# Dispersion law for a tight binding Hamiltonian and particle states at $t$$\rightarrow$$\infty$

Tags: solid-state-physics, hamiltonian, dispersion, tight-binding

[image: Tight binding hamiltonian]
[image: Lattice configure]

A spinless fermion (possessing an electric charge) can move across the sites of
the discrete (translationally-invariant) lattice. The structure
features three kinds of sites: $α_n$, $β_n$, $γ_n$  with $n = 1,...,N$ and $N ≫ 1$.
For each n, $α_n$, $β_n$ and $γ_n$ share the same x-coordinate $t_n$ = $na$. The particle can directly hop between nearest-neighbour sites $α_n$ and $α_n$$_+$$_1$, between sites $α_n-β_n$ (same n) and between sites $α_n-γ_n$ (same n).

Due tight-binding model I derived the energy spectrum of the particle, showing that it comprises three energy bands $E_+(k)$, $E_-(k)$ and $E_0(k)=0$. Now, I have to find the dispersion laws.
Why do I have a flat energy band? What is its physical significance?. Also, what happens to the particle to $t \rightarrow \infty$ if the state at $t = 0$ is in a generic site $|Ψ(0)> = |β_m>$?

Comment: Can you edit your question and title to make it a little bit clearer  ?

Comment: $E_0(k)=0 ;  E_{\pm}(k)=-Jcos(ka){\pm}\sqrt{J^2cos^2(ka)+g_c^2+g_b^2}$

These are the energy bands that I found.

Comment: I am not able to answer your question properly. I would say that the dispersion relations are the $E(k)$ that you already found. I do not know about the flat energy band. But I know that if a particle starts at $t=0$ in a generic state, it will end up being delocalized in all the structure

Comment: The fact that I have a flat band could mean that there is a delocalization of the particle, but that it has no probability that it tends to zero to be in the initial state when $ t \rightarrow \infty $, right?

Comment: As far as I know, the delocalization of the electrons is quite generic in these kinds of periodic systems and not related to the flat band. What this means is basically that (after some relaxation time if you initially put in a given site) your electron will behave as a free wave with $\left|\psi\right>\propto e^{ikx}$